# python: data structure efficiency between list and dictionary

Tags: python, list, data-structures, dictionary

I need to add item or edit item in a list or a dictionary.

The list is smth like
    `[10, 15, 42, 78]`

The dictionary is smth like
    `{0: 10, 1: 15, 2: 42, 3: 78}`

Which one is more efficient?

Comment: Just go with `list`. There is no point having a `dictionary` in this specific case

Comment: https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity

Comment: Though `dictionary` will give you faster performance on lookups e.g while editing, but for your situation `list` is a better choice.

Comment: Give a list of all the operations you need to do and if you want to keep the data sorted. Efficiency depends purely on what you need done. On a side note, I recall seeing a flow chart for which data structure should be used in a given situation. It might be useful for those asking questions if that flow chart was shown above the question as they typed it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It really depends.

When you are testing membership (i.e. `needle in haystack`) dictionaries are the better choice (as this runs in O(1) as opposed to O(n) on lists). When you're iterating over the values, lists are the way to go.

There are several efficiency trade-offs between the two, and each situation requires a different analysis. There is no 'best' data structure.

Have a look at [this page](https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity) for an elaborate comparison of runtimes of various operations on lists, deques, dicts and sets.

Answer (score -3):

Depends what you mean by efficiency.

When it comes to speed, list will be faster but dictionary is more easy to organize and access with keys.

Comment: "When it comes to speed, list will be faster"? When it comes to speed doing what?

Comment: memory and iteration.

Comment: So the memory will be faster when using list? What has speed to do with memory?